# Volley throws NullPointerException invoking interface method writeRequestHeaders()

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to make a simple Volley request from an Android app created with Android Studio 3.0.1 on Win10. A `NullPointerException` is thrown when I make a Volley request while running on a Nexus 5X emulator with API 26.

I haven't found anyone else with the same problem, but I've re-created the problem by creating a new project and copy-pasting the activity code. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the stack trace:

```
12-29 13:56:19.839 26070-26204/com.test.myapp E/Volley: [773] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpStream.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpStream.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:593)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
   at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.trackResponse(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:86)
   at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.tryTrackResponse(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:101)
   at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:308)
   at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLConnection$.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection$.java:92)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:99)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
   at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
   at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
12-29 13:56:19.846 26070-26070/com.test.myapp E/test: That didn't work! com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpStream.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
```

The AndroidManifest.xml has INTERNET permissions, and my build.gradle file has a dependency on the latest Volley library:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The lone activity has a button that when pressed makes the Volley request using code that was copy-pasted from the [Android Volley doc](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html):

```
package com.test.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject);
    }

    private void makeRequest() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://www.google.com";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.d("test", "Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("test","That didn't work! " + error);
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        makeRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable. Turns out I had a stray space at the end of the permission line in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET "/>
```

should have been

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Why there was no complaint about the lack of INTERNET permissions, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899. Create the class and pass the second param.Check if it works.

Comment: That gist may be out of date. When I tried to run the code, it complained that the call to `client.open` is not defined. 

I'm not wanting to use a work-around, If at all possible I want to use the Volley library as intended in the Android documentation.